# Prefill realm database swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'd like to use local realm database within the app without any backend connection and I would like to populate this database with initial data. I can't find any documentation on this.

I have:

1. Described models (as objects extended from RealmSwift)
2. Data that I
   want to put in my realm db.

What is the correct flow for putting my data into the realm db and saving it?

Thank you!

Comment: Without knowing what format your data is in, it's quite hard to answer. However, in any case, you'll need to implement the logic yourself for populating the Realm with your own data, there are no built-in methods for this. Just do it once, then save the Realm file and use that instead of the default empty Realm when shipping your app.

Comment: This should be straightforward; on App launch test to see of the Realm exists. If so, assume it has the default/user data. If not, create your Realm objects with default values and write it to realm. Other than the Realm Objects themselves, should be about 5 lines of code (or more if you've got an assortment of different objects)

Comment: @Jay there's no need to create the Realm itself in runtime. The Realm can be prefilled with values during development, then the prefilled Realm file can be shipped with the app.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Of course. I wasn't suggesting to not do that. The OP didn't ask if it should be shipped with a Realm file or have it created on the fly so I was just taking the on the fly route. Either way, the process is similar. Fill it before and ship with, or ship without and build on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Realm Browser from the App Store and you can edit an empty realm file or you can import a scheme from a csv or xlsx file. Then save that and include it when you are shipping your app like @David-Pasztor said.

Note that you must have the scheme generated by your code first, and then you can copy the realm file generated and add rows and values.